# How to prevent SwiftUI View in background shrinking on overriding View in .sheet(isPresented:) become almost full screen?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want on opening max height content with .sheet(isPresented:), not to animate and shrink content behind (in red rectangle). Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Maybe just use a `ZStack` and implement your own covering layer?

Comment: @BenzyNeez I already have one since iOS 14. Want to use more native approach for newer iOS versions.

Comment: That sounds like a [`fullScreenCover`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/fullscreencover(ispresented:ondismiss:content:)) to me.

Comment: No, @Sweeper. fullScreenCover will cover all the screen to the most top. I need little space left, like it is in .sheet behaviour, but View behind stays without any change/animation.

Comment: There is a modifier for that, I can’t remember if SwiftUI has it but you can do it with UIKit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The background view gets smaller when the presentation detent is too large. You can see that the background view does not get smaller when using a `.medium` detent for example.

Presumably there is a threshold for presentation detents, and if you go above that threshold, the background view gets smaller. You can set the detent to something just below that threshold.

What I've found to work is `.fraction(0.999)`, or a custom detent whose height is 1 less than the maximum height.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var x = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("Click") {
            x = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $x) {
            Text("Foo")
                .presentationDetents([
                    .custom(CustomDetent.self) // or .fraction(0.999)
                ])
        }
    }
}

struct CustomDetent: CustomPresentationDetent {
    static func height(in context: Context) -> CGFloat? {
        return context.maxDetentValue - 1
    }
}
```