SwiftUI View zooms out when keyboard appears
I can't seem to find the answer to this problem but I apologize if it has already been answered. In my main content view, I have a button that shows another view as a sheet. This sheet contains a text field and whenever I click on it to open the keyboard, the original view seems to zoom out a little bit.
Before clicking on the textfield:

After:

If anyone has any suggestions that would be great!

The keyboard pushes the sheet up, and this is what happens when the sheet is high enough on the screen (see also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77799994/5133585). You can make the sheet detent smaller so the sheet doesn't get pushed to the very top, but other than that there is little you can do about this. You'd have to make your own sheet.
